# DRYing up some Rails/HAML/jQuery view code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, refactoring, haml, dry

I render an alert bar as a partial at the top of the screen that gets shown to the user for success/failure/notice flash messages.

I finally have it working for most scenarios, but the code itself is repetitive for a few parts and I am not sure how I can split it up more efficiently since I am relatively new to all of this.  My goal is to try not to repeat myself if possible or at least to minimize how much is repeated.

For instance, is there a way to place some of the javascript into a re-useable partial or helper function? Are there other obvious ways of making this code less repetitious?

I'm not comfortable enough yet with Rails/Ruby to understand how to improve the code, so any tips you can provide are greatly appreciated!

```
/ top alert area
#topAlertBar.shadow_medium.soft-hidden

- if flash.empty? && !current_user.confirmed?
  - # User has yet to confirm their account
  - # and there AREN'T any flash messages to show

  #alertBarOffset.colordark.soft-hidden
    / placeholder for alert bar offset

  :javascript
    // Set the flash box content
    $('#topAlertBar').html('Please confirm your account by following the instructions sent to #{current_user.email}.  To resend your confirmation email, #{escape_javascript(link_to("click here", user_resend_confirmation_path(current_user), :class => "inlinelink", :method => :post, :remote => true))} #{escape_javascript(image_tag("ajaxOrange.gif", :class => "soft-hidden mls mbs"))}.');

    // Slides down the top alert bar after page load
    $('#topAlertBar, #alertBarOffset').delay(250).slideDown("fast");

    // Shows & hides AJAX loading GIF when necessary
    $('#topAlertBar a').click(function() {
      $(document).bind('ajaxSend', function(e, request, options) {
        $("#topAlertBar img").show();
      });
      $(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(e, request, options) {
        $(document).unbind('ajaxSend', 'ajaxComplete');
        $("#topAlertBar img").hide();
      });
    });

- elsif !flash.empty? && !current_user.confirmed?
  - # User has yet to confirm their account
  - # and there ARE flash messages to show

  #alertBarOffset.colordark.soft-hidden
    / placeholder for alert bar offset

  - [:error, :success, :notice].each do |key| 
    - unless flash[key].blank?
      - @msg = flash[key]
      - @key = key

  :javascript
    // Set the flash box content
    var $that = $('#topAlertBar');
    $that.html('#{@msg}').addClass('#{@key}').delay(250).slideDown("fast", function() {
      $(this).delay(2000).slideUp("fast", function () {
        // Remove any CSS modifiers
        $that.removeClass('#{@key}');

        // Set the flash box content
        $('#topAlertBar').html('Please confirm your account by following the instructions sent to #{current_user.email}.  To resend your confirmation email, #{escape_javascript(link_to("click here", user_resend_confirmation_path(current_user), :class => "inlinelink", :method => :post, :remote => true))} #{escape_javascript(image_tag("ajaxOrange.gif", :class => "soft-hidden mls mbs"))}.');

        // Slides down the top alert bar after page load
        $('#topAlertBar, #alertBarOffset').slideDown("fast");

        // Shows & hides AJAX loading GIF when necessary
        $('#topAlertBar a').click(function() {
          $(document).bind('ajaxSend', function(e, request, options) {
            $("#topAlertBar img").show();
          });
          $(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(e, request, options) {
            $(document).unbind('ajaxSend', 'ajaxComplete');
            $("#topAlertBar img").hide();
          });
        });

      });
    });


- elsif !flash.empty?
  - # User is confirmed
  - # and there ARE flash messages to show

  - [:error, :success, :notice].each do |key| 
    - unless flash[key].blank?
      - @msg = flash[key]
      - @key = key

  :javascript
    // Set the flash box content
    var $that = $('#topAlertBar');
    $that.html('#{@msg}').addClass('#{@key}').delay(250).slideDown("fast", function() {
      $(this).delay(2000).slideUp("fast");
    });
```

Comment: By the way, this question was originally posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but apparently no one actually goes there and reviews code so I migrated it back to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a different approach than what Jesse recommended, but he still helped get me thinking about ways to refactor the code.  Here is the end result which is as DRY as I could get it without completely changing how I already had it implemented.

Hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles upon this question in the future.

---

**In my ApplicationHelper** (this is modified somewhat from the original question so it now works for my validation errors as well as regular flash messages)

```
  def display_flash_messages
    if !flash.empty?
      [:error, :success, :notice, :warning].each do |key| 
        unless flash[key].blank?
          @flash_key = key
          if flash[key].kind_of?(Array) && flash[key].size > 1
            @flash_msg = flash[key].join(' & ')
          elsif flash[key].kind_of?(Array) && flash[key].size == 1
            @flash_msg = flash[key].first
          elsif flash[key].kind_of?(String)
            @flash_msg = flash[key]
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return
  end
```

**In my main layout file, I'm just doing:**

```
  %body
    - if signed_in?
      = render 'shared/top_alert_bar'
```

**In the top alert bar file**

```
= display_flash_messages

/ top alert area
#topAlertBar.shadow_medium.soft-hidden
- if !current_user.confirmed?
  #alertBarOffset.colordark.soft-hidden
    / placeholder for alert bar offset

- if flash.empty? && !current_user.confirmed?
  - # User has yet to confirm their account
  - # and there AREN'T any flash messages to show

  :javascript
    #{render('shared/js/confirm_user')}

- elsif !flash.empty?

  :javascript
    // Set the flash box content
    var $that = $('#topAlertBar');
    $that.html('#{@flash_msg}').addClass('#{@flash_key}').delay(250).slideDown("fast", function() {
      $(this).delay(4000).slideUp("fast", function () {
        // Remove any CSS modifiers
        $that.removeClass('#{@flash_key}');

        #{!current_user.confirmed? ? render('shared/js/confirm_user') : ""}

      });
    });
```

**In the confirm_user partial**

```
:plain
  $('#topAlertBar').html('Please confirm your account by following the instructions sent to #{current_user.email}.  To resend your confirmation email, #{escape_javascript(link_to('click here', user_resend_confirmation_path(current_user), :class => 'inlinelink', :method => :post, :remote => true))}. #{escape_javascript(image_tag('ajaxOrange.gif', :class => 'soft-hidden mls mbs'))}');

  $('#topAlertBar, #alertBarOffset').delay(250).slideDown('fast');
```

**And finally, I moved this to my main js file**

```
/* ******************************** */
/* Top Alert Bar for Flash Messages */
/* ******************************** */
// Description: Shows & hides AJAX loading GIF when necessary
$('#topAlertBar a').click(function() {
  $(document).bind('ajaxSend', function(e, request, options) {
    $("#topAlertBar img").show();
  });
  $(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(e, request, options) {
    $("#topAlertBar img").hide();
    $(document).unbind('ajaxSend', 'ajaxComplete');
  });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with all the different states of user confirmation? Just have your application_controller set a flash alert if the user isn't confirmed.

Secondly -- move all the jquery to application.js and run it on every page -- it should slide your content down if it exists, otherwise do nothing.

Finally, grab a flash helper like the following: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6440 and then call it in your layout like

```
%head
  %titile
  =javascript_include_tag :all
  =yield(:header)
%body
  =display_flash
  =yield
```

Comment: Parts of this would work for me if I weren't setting Ruby objects in the HAML jQuery code like this: `$that.html('#{@msg}').addClass('#{@key}')` ..However, I'm not sure your solution would work for me for that reason.

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just have jquery grab the content if it exists

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Jesse; they helped get my brain moving this morning.  I ended up doing it a little differently since I didn't want to recreate the system I already had in place.